# append all Integers of an integer in a list in python using recursive function

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion

I need an example of a recursive function that will append all integer elements of a number into a list using python and doing this with the most basic algorithm.

For example if `n = 1234`, list will be `[1,2,3,4]`.

Comment: This is not a code providing platform. You should do your own efford and add your best not-working attempt.

Comment: Add your attempt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this?

```
def numberToList(number):

    # base case
    if number == 0:
        return []

    # recurse
    return numberToList(number / 10) + [ number % 10 ]
```

Run it like this:

```
>>> numberToList(1234)
[4, 3, 2, 1]
```

Comment: Thanks for downvoting a perfectly good answer...